# How do I use multiple rows in a frame to get one classification?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

For example, I have ~500 5x5 data frames like the following:

```
           Weight     Color       Shape     Chemical   Product      
Apple        0.1       Pink       heart        0          1
Orange       0.2       Orange    sphere        0          1
Strawberry   0.01      White      heart        1          1
Watermelon   1.72      Green      square       0          1
Pear         0           0           0         0          0
```

This data frame correspond to the country - Japan. In other words, my input will be this dataset and the output will be Japan. And my problem is: I know the countries of about ~70% of all the datasets, how can I use predict the country with this format of data? Basically, my question is:

I looked into this post [Classification Model with multiple records per user](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440566/classification-model-with-multiple-records-per-user?rq=1) but I still have no idea how to do this, i am using R.

Comment: In short, you have a data frame from which you would like to make 1 prediction, based on the whole data frame? How do the other data frames look like? Do they have the same structure? Could you put all the rows in the columns, so that you have only 1 row per country?

Comment: I think I might have an idea on how to do this, thank you!

Comment: @user2974951 I tried putting all the data into 1 row per country but it ends up having 16 columns and the prediction is not so great (> 50%).

Comment: I don't see a problem with having 16 columns. Predictions not being great is a whole other issue. You should ask a new question stating exactly what you've done and your results.